# Query a table with json format

Tags: sql, json

I would like to know how can I read with a sql query a table like that:
(this is just an example)

```
id,date,information
1,2018-26-02,{[{"iteration_number":0,"data":{"name":"Toto",values:{"PV":78,"SV":20,"TV":19},"state":"ok"},{"iteration_number":1,"data":{"name":"Baba",values:{"PV":68,"SV":10,"TV":11},"state":"ok"}}}]}
```

For example, to select the date of the first record, I will write: "SELECT date FROM table1 WHERE id=1;

But if I just would like the name of the iteration number 0 ? (Toto)

Say me if I'm not understandable.

Thanks for your response.

Simon

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? I think the answer might be dependent on that.

Comment: SQL is designed for database queries, not parsing arbitrary JSON. If you need such data, you should redefine your database schema to expose that information instead of leaving it hidden in an opaque JSON blob.

Comment: In fact, I export the data from an application, the data are saved in .db file with sqlite format 3. So, to read it, I use SQLite data browser.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL there is a `JSON_VALUE` function you can use for this:

More documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server).

```
DECLARE @temp_table TABLE
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    information VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @temp_table
    (date, information)
VALUES 
    (GETDATE(), '[{"iteration_number":1,"data":{"name":"Toto",values:{"PV":78,"SV":20,"TV":19},"state":"ok"},{"iteration_number":1,"data":{"name":"Baba",values:{"PV":68,"SV":10,"TV":11},"state":"ok"}}}]');


SELECT date, JSON_VALUE(information,'$[0].data.name') AS Name
FROM @temp_table
```